# How to add last column of table as a whole row in RDLC report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I created RDLC report and added one table having fields like

**Sr No,Item Code, Qty, Unit, Drg No,Long Description**

I want Long Description field as a separate row after each record.

Can you please guide me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in SSRS designer click in the table row (detail) select insert row below and merge all columns as required for your new field

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).